# Debug F# Type Provider build

Tags: debugging, compilation, f#, type-providers

I can debug my type provider's design time consumption by starting another Visual Studio instance then loading the debug symbols and attaching to the instance consuming the TP.

This process allows me to stop at breakpoints, step over, catch exceptions etc. which is great.

Given that it is possible for issues to arise when the consuming code is *built* but not to show up at design time, my question is:

Is it possible to debug the *build* of the consuming application in a similar way?

Comment: Attach to the compiler?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin any idea how to do that? The visual studio process is long running so I can start it running, attach the second instamce, THEN do xyz to move into my code. The compilation takes seconds. How do I 'pause' it to enable me to attach a the debugger?

Comment: You might be able to configure the F# compiler process to start under the debugger - see [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/greggm/2005/02/21/inside-image-file-execution-options-debugging/)

Comment: You can start the compiler right from under Visual Studio. Just got o File -> Open and select `fsc.exe`, VS will create a dummy solutiuon with `fsc.exe` as the startup object, then you can right-click it and specify parameters.